# photo download in react native iOS is too slow

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fs, rn-fetch-blob

I need to download 1000s of photos in react native for offline use. 
I use RNFetchBlob for android and RNFS for iOS to download all photos.

**for android**

```
       RNFetchBlob.config({
            path: `${Path.path}${fileName}.${type}`,
            fileCache: true
        }).fetch('GET', result, {})
        .progress((received, total) => {

        }).then(async res => {
            deletePhoto(id)
            console.log('downloaded', res)
        }).catch((error) => {
            downloadFile(fileName, result, type, id)
            console.log('error in file download', id)
        })
```

**for iOS**

```
        RNFS.downloadFile({
            fromUrl: result,
            toFile:`${Path.path}${fileName}.${type}`,
            background: true,
            connectionTimeout: 1000 * 10,
            readTimeout: 1000 * 10,
            discretionary: true,
            progressDivider: 1,
            progress: (res) => {
            // do progress
            }
        }).promise.then((result) => {
            console.log('downloaded', result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error in file download', error)
        })
```

**Problem**

Time taken for downloading 800 files is for android - *2-3 minute* depends on network-bandwidth and for **iOS 20 minutes**  I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help will be useful to me 
*thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't wrote anything about the size of the Images.
But if you have to load a huge amount of Images which has at least a big amount of Data, I would suggest to "re-think" the strategy you handle your Images in your App.

**If you definitely need all this Images offline**, the peak of loading those Images is only at first App-Startup. Afterwards you only check and sync if there are new, changed or deleted images at the server since last download.

1. In this case I would suggest to download the images as Blocks. That means... figure out, what the very first images are, that the user expect to see, and load them in a first download-process.
   For all the other places, where images should appear (but not yet loaded), you output a message like: "Please wait. Initialization is in progress".
   Then you load - still by priority - the other files step by step.
2. Another solution could be to have thumbs with really low filesize/quality at the server and first load them for all places, where images should appear... afterwards load the images step by step in the Background.
3. If your Images don't change that much, you can think about to still bundle some of the needed images into your APK. This increase the APK-Size, but give you a little boosted Startup for first images (use this only as bad-whorst-case workaround. I didn't recommend this!)

**Otherwise, if you `don't` need all Images offline**, you might preload images, if you enter the screen (where the images expected).

At least I would suggest to rethink the strategy to show images in your App. Don't act like in Webpages in 1998 - and load all images at page-init!

You better load images by need (lazy-loading). There are some components for this out there.. and even the core-Component -Komponent can help you with that, if you implement it in the right way.

Hope that helps you a bit.

Comment: Size of an single image (thumbnail) is from 5kb to 10kb

Comment: I know how to load file in app but in my scenario i have to download all thumbnail at the time of login our app. so that I can use those thumbnail in case i have no internet connectivity.

Comment: My simple question is what wrong I am doing so iOS is taking too much time for downloading files ?

Comment: You don't wrote anything about your *strategy to load* your images. To know the technically way to get files into your app isn't 100% of the solution... that's why I talk about `Strategy to load`.
But if you think your strategy is fine, and it work technically... tell me: How else can anybody help you with suggestions?!!

Comment: As I already mentioned My Solution is working great in android but having problem with iOS just want to know where I am doing wrong so that thumbnail downloading is taking so much time in iOS ?